# SquirrelSQL custom driver cannot find file

Tags: java, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I have written a custom JDBC driver. It relies on configuration files. It works well when deployed as a typical Java application, with the configuration files copied to the class path.

I would like to use it with SquirrelSQL. And I cannot use this custom driver because the configuration files have not been found. I have copied the files into the squirrel /lib directory, and to the root directory, but this did not work.

Do you have any idea of where I should copy the configuration files?

Comment: Maybe try putting the configuration files in a JAR file and put that JAR file in the lib directory?

Comment: Please use a dedicated UI function to add the driver. There you can define the path to your software. https://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.io/user-manual/quick_start.html#the_driver

Comment: Putting jar file made it work. Thank you